# Can a Transport Rule be used to change the FROM address of outbound email?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2013, outlook-2010

I have users who have 5 domains and they need to send FROM each one.  Normally this entails setting up a new mailbox and the subsequent hassle on the mobile devices and local profile.

I would like to come up with a more efficient solution.  Is there a way to use Transport Rules or other SMTP magic to allow end users to send FROM more than one domain (e.g. a secondary email address)

Perhaps a special tag in the subject line would trigger this rule `[domain.com]` for outbound email.

Is this a workable idea, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any native Exchange feature that can do this as you're describing. I'm not aware of any third-party add-ons either, but it would be worth investigating.

If this is a frequent thing, you might want to set up a third-party webmail interface that can more easily do this in the interface or via backend rules, and then make sure that its SMTP engine uses Exchange as a smarthost, and that Exchange has a receive connector that will allow the SMTP engine's IP to relay mail.